# Alternate value than null

Tags: t-sql, null, where-clause, coalesce, isnull

As you know null never equals null in SQL.

Let's pretend we have a query like this:

```
declare @LastName varchar(50) = 'Nixon';
select * from Users 
    where LastName = @LastName;
```

If I want to allow the variable to be null, I do this:

```
declare @LastName varchar(50) = 'Nixon';
select * from Users 
    where LastName = IsNull(@LastName, LastName);
```

But what if LastName is null? I must do this:

```
declare @Null varchar(50) = '!{-[~]-}!'; -- any-ole gibberish

declare @LastName varchar(50) = 'Nixon';
select * from Users 
    where IsNull(LastName, @Null) = Coalesce(@LastName, LastName, @Null);
```

This works just fine, and I see many similar approaches out there.

But my question is: **is this really the best approach?** It seems to me that this is a kludge, but I have thought about it a lot and simply cannot come up with anything better.

**EDIT** but this seems best:

```
declare @LastName varchar(50) = 'Nixon';
select * from Users 
    where (@LastName is null) or (@LastName = LastName);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't it be simpler to do this?

```
declare @LastName varchar(50) = 'Nixon';

SELECT * FROM users
  WHERE (@LastName IS NULL) OR (@LastName = LastName);
```

Comment: That is not the same logic. For example if @LastName is not null and LastName is null then your logic would render unexpected results. This is because my logic above does NOT return all results if the LastName is null. Not at all.

Comment: Do you mean perhaps the second query I just added?

Comment: Yes, that is the correct logic, but far more complicated than my sample. I see how it is less kludgy, to your credit.

Comment: I think it more clearly expresses your intent than creating a variable named @Null that does not contain Null.

Comment: Your logic is still not correct, I see now. This is because a null @LastName actually should equate to ALL records. In your case, it would only equate to null records. This is incorrect.

Comment: @JerryNixon let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2670/discussion-between-daniel-lyons-and-jerry-nixon)

Comment: This can lead to sub optimal plans unless `RECOMPILE` is used and even then it is version dependant as to whether this will resolve the issue. See http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html